# How to build tree in Binary Search Tree node in MIPS assembly?

Tags: mips

Using the c code below:

```
void insert(node ** tree, int val)
{
    node *temp = NULL;
    if(!(*tree))
    {
        temp = (node *)malloc(sizeof(node));
        temp->left = temp->right = NULL;
        temp->data = val;
        *tree = temp;
        return;
    }

    if(val < (*tree)->data)
    {
        insert(&(*tree)->left, val);
    }
    else if(val > (*tree)->data)
    {
        insert(&(*tree)->right, val);
    }

}
```

I don't know how to start with a pointer to nothing, and then make a another node with value, &left, &right. In other words, when traversing the pointer of the node to the left, how would I make the current pointer point the left node and then point outwards as if pointing at the same object of the left.

How to make move left/right?

```
right:      

    addi     $a3, $a3, 8

    jal build

or
    right:      

    la a3, 8($a3)

    jal build
```

Answer (score 1):

If you'll use bare metal mips, you won't have an OS to manage your dynamic allocation, so you'll need to make your own allocator, or just use a global pool of nodes.

If you're ussing an OS, just call the appropriate function / syscall.

You can't use stack allocation, as that memory should be freed when `include()` goes out of scope.

---

When you don't know how to do something, the easiest is letting gcc do the work for you.

To output readable but uncommented assembly, use

```
gcc -S -O0 src.c
```

To get the original C code as comments, but on decompiled assembly, use.

```
gcc -c src.c  -g -O0
objdump  -S src.o  > out.S
```

By manually comparing both outputs you can build a good understanding on how to do something.

In your case, on the slightly modified code:

```
typedef struct node { int data; struct node * left; struct node * right; } node;

node node_pool[30];
node pool_index = 29;

void insert(node ** tree, int val)
{
    node *temp = NULL;
    if(!(*tree))
    {
        temp = &node_pool[pool_index]; 
        temp->left = temp->right = NULL;
        temp->data = val;
        *tree = temp;
        return;
    }

    if(val < (*tree)->data)
    {
        insert(&(*tree)->left, val);
    }
    else if(val > (*tree)->data)
    {
        insert(&(*tree)->right, val);
    }

}
```

This is the manually commented assembly. Note it's using [mips elf abi](https://www.linux-mips.org/pub/linux/mips/doc/ABI/MIPS-N32-ABI-Handbook.pdf) on the function call.

```
    .comm   node_pool,360,4
#node node_pool[30];

    .globl  pool_index
    .data
    .align  2
    .type   pool_index, @object
    .size   pool_index, 4
pool_index:
    .word   29
#unsigned int  pool_index = 29;

    .text
    .align  2
    .globl  insert
    .set    nomips16
    .set    nomicromips
    .ent    insert
    .type   insert, @function
insert:
    .frame  $fp,40,$31      # vars= 8, regs= 2/0, args= 16, gp= 8
    .mask   0xc0000000,-4
    .fmask  0x00000000,0
    .set    noreorder
    .set    nomacro



    addiu   $sp,$sp,-40
    sw  $31,36($sp)
    sw  $fp,32($sp)
    move    $fp,$sp
    sw  $4,40($fp)
    sw  $5,44($fp)
    sw  $0,24($fp)
    #void insert(node ** tree, int val)
#{

    lw  $2,40($fp)
    lw  $2,0($2)
    bne $2,$0,$L2
    nop

#temp = &node_pool[pool_index--]; 
    lui $2,%hi(pool_index)
    lw  $3,%lo(pool_index)($2)
    move    $2,$3
    sll $2,$2,2
    sll $4,$2,2
    subu    $4,$4,$2
    lui $2,%hi(node_pool)
    addiu   $2,$2,%lo(node_pool)
    addu    $2,$4,$2
    sw  $2,24($fp)
    addiu   $3,$3,-1
    lui $2,%hi(pool_index)
    sw  $3,%lo(pool_index)($2)
#temp->left = temp->right = NULL;
    lw  $2,24($fp)
    sw  $0,8($2)
    lw  $2,24($fp)
    lw  $3,8($2)
    lw  $2,24($fp)
    sw  $3,4($2)
    lw  $2,24($fp)
    lw  $3,44($fp)
    sw  $3,0($2)
    lw  $2,40($fp)
    lw  $3,24($fp)
    sw  $3,0($2)
    j   $L1
    nop
#if(val < (*tree)->data){
$L2:
    lw  $2,40($fp)
    lw  $2,0($2)
    lw  $3,0($2)
    lw  $2,44($fp)
    slt $2,$2,$3
    beq $2,$0,$L4
    nop

    lw  $2,40($fp)
    lw  $2,0($2)
    addiu   $2,$2,4
    move    $4,$2
    lw  $5,44($fp)
    jal insert
    nop

    j   $L1
    nop

#insert(&(*tree)->left, val);
# }

$L4:
    lw  $2,40($fp)
    lw  $2,0($2)
    lw  $3,0($2)
    lw  $2,44($fp)
    slt $2,$3,$2
    beq $2,$0,$L1
    nop

    lw  $2,40($fp)
    lw  $2,0($2)
    addiu   $2,$2,8
    move    $4,$2
    lw  $5,44($fp)
    jal insert
    nop

# else if(val > (*tree)->data){
#    insert(&(*tree)->right, val);
# }

$L1:
    move    $sp,$fp
    lw  $31,36($sp)
    lw  $fp,32($sp)
    addiu   $sp,$sp,40
    j   $31
    nop
```

---